# High memory usage in play 2.4.6 application

Tags: java, scala, memory, memory-management, playframework

I have application written in Play 2.4.6(Scala). When application was deployed on production, it took around 1.4 GB memory(captured RSS top).
Heap usage of service goes around 2.5 GB and then it drops to 500 MB. Initially I was suspecting memory leak but heap gets cleaned after some time.
However even after heap usage gets reduced, there is no change in residual memory used by application. There is constant growth in residual memory usage of application.
I am unable to understand what's going wrong here. Is this related to some configuration(java memory parameters) or my code is causing this? How can I avoid growth in residual memory usage?

Heap Parameters while running application: -J-Xms2G -J-Xmx8G

NOTE: I am using scala 2.11.8, Java 8 and Akka 2.4.4.

build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8" 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
  ws, 
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.0.12", 
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2",
  "org.apache.shiro" % "shiro-core" % "1.2.2", 
  "org.apache.shiro" % "shiro-ehcache" % "1.2.2", 
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.4", 
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.4", 
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % "2.4.4", 
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.4.4", 
  "com.tuplejump.utils" %% "xformer" % "0.0.1" 
) 

resolvers ++= Seq( 
    "sgodbillon" at "bitbucket.org/sgodbillon/repository/raw/master/snapshots/&q‌​uot;,
    "terracotta" at "terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases"; 
)
```

plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/";

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")
```

Comment: Can you paste your `plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt`?

Comment: I am not able to paste it as new line is not shown here correctly.

Comment: lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
ws,
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.0.12",
"net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2",
"org.apache.shiro" % "shiro-core" % "1.2.2",
"org.apache.shiro" % "shiro-ehcache" % "1.2.2",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.4",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.4",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % "2.4.4",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.4.4",
"com.tuplejump.utils" %% "xformer" % "0.0.1"
)
Partial data

Comment: resolvers ++= Seq(
"sgodbillon" at "https://bitbucket.org/sgodbillon/repository/raw/master/snapshots/",
"terracotta" at "http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases"
)

remaining contents in build.sbt

Comment: resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

plugins.sbt

Comment: you could edit your question and add those .sbt contents there, that would be more readable

Comment: Does this memory usage manifest after startup before your application starts to manage tasks? I would have a think about what your application is doing on startup eg. I see you are interacting with Cassandra - are you running any queries on startup? Are you writing data into ehcache? If so, how much memory is this data likely to consume?

Comment: After startup and before any request is served, memory usage i.e. RSS increases and stop at some point. When requests are served then RSS and heap start to grow. Heap gets cleaned after some time but RSS never. I am not writing any data to ehcache. Only data is read from cassandra.

Comment: I also observed that when OS memory is about to exhaust then RSS is freed. But till that time RSS keeps increasing. I observed this behavior in local environment which has 512 MB RAM. However on production(looking at current rate of growth in RSS), it will take a month or more to exhaust OS memory.